# A difficult one to many mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables, one being "users" and one being "social networks". I want to grab data from both in a certain format, and the social networks table has user_id as a column.

I want to end up with something like

```
array{
    0 => array{
        name => "Bob",
        id => 1,
        facebook => array{ <all data from the fb row> },
        twitter => array{ <all data from the tw row> },
        linkedin => array{ <all data from the li row> }
    },
    1 => array{
        name => "Jill",
        id => 2,
        facebook => array{ <all data from the fb row> },
        twitter => array{ <all data from the tw row> },
        linkedin => array{ <all data from the li row> }
    }
}
```

Is this possible?

Edit for clarity:

The social_networks table looks something like:

user_id, social_network, account_url, etc.

And the user table looks like:

id, name, picture, etc.

Where user_id from the social_networks table matches id from the users table. Each user can have several rows in the social_networks table.

What I'm trying to grab is the entire row from the users table and each respective row from the social networks table. I would prefer to do this in a single query.

Comment: Without seeing the structure of the tables, it's pretty hard to say.

Comment: What is the structure of the "social networks" table?

Comment: What do you mean by "all data from fb row"? Is it all fb related rows from the social network table?

Comment: I will edit to be more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it directly through mysql, but you can do it fairly easily. Here is the pseudocode:

```
// connect to database
// query for all users
// foreach user
  // add user to array
  // add user's fb info to array
  // add user's tw info to array
  // add user's li info to array
```

In a little more detail (using PDO, since I won't even pretend that mysql_* is okay).

```
<?php

// create a PDO object to connect to the db
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb', 'username', 'password');

// get a basic list of users with their IDs and names
$query = $pdo->query('select user_id, name from users');

// prepare the final array that will hold it all
$users = array();

// loop through the users returned by the query
while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  // make an array for this user with the basic data
  $user = array('id' => $row['user_id'], 'name' => $row['name']);

  // add fb data
  $user['fb'] = $pdo->prepare('select * from fb where user_id = :user_id')
    ->execute(array(':user_id' => $user['id']))
    ->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


  // add li data
  $user['li'] = $pdo->prepare('select * from li where user_id = :user_id')
    ->execute(array(':user_id' => $user['id']))
    ->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

  // add tw data
  $user['tw'] = $pdo->prepare('select * from tw where user_id = :user_id')
    ->execute(array(':user_id' => $user['id']))
    ->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

  // add new user to the full array
  $users[] = $user;
}

// do stuff with the $users array
```

Answer (score 1):

So you could do something like

```
SELECT u.ID, u.Name, s.* FROM users u
INNER JOIN socialNetworks s ON u.ID = s.user_id
ORDER BY u.ID
```

And loop through identical ID's, building your array for each user:

```
$id = -1;
$i = 0;
$userArr = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res))
{
    //parse row set user/SN info

    if($id != $row["ID"])
    {
        $tempUserArr = array();
        $id = $row["ID"];
        //set user and sn info to $tempUserArr
        $userArr[] = $tempUserArr;
    }
    else
    {
        $tempSN_arr = array();
        //set social network info to $tempSN_arr
        $userArr[$i][$row["sn_type"]] = $tempSN_arr;
    }
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: In this case if I had one user with multiple rows in the SN table I would end up with multiple rows where the user information was duplicate. I'm hoping to grab the user and corresponding SN rows together in the format described above.

Comment: Sorry, I terribly misunderstood. Hopefully this is more help.

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user";
$rows = mysql_query($sql);


$user_array = array()

while($record = mysql_fetch_array($orws){

   $new_array = array();
   $new_array['name']  = $record['name'];
   $new_array['id']  =$record['user_id'];
   $new_array['facebook'] = array(); //function or query to fill data
   $new_array['twitter'] = array();//function or query to fill data
   $new_array['linkedin'] = array();//function or query to fill data

     $user_array[]=$new_array;
}
print_r($user_array);
```

Comment: I'm am trying to achieve this using one query, I don't want to make too many connections to the DB.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternate to my other answer, this one will get you all the data in one query:

```
select
  users.id,
  users.name,
  fb.account_url as 'facebook_account_url',
  li.account_url as 'linkedin_account_url',
  tw.account_url as 'twitter_account_url',
from
  users
  inner join social_network as fb on users.id = fb.user_id and fb.social_network = 'fb'
  inner join social_network as tw on users.id = tw.user_id and tw.social_network = 'tw'
  inner join social_network as li on users.id = li.user_id and li.social_network = 'li'
```

The resulting data will not be a multidimensional array like you showed in the question, but it will be done in a single MySQL query.